# Laravel 5.2 Pagination Customization

Tags: php, laravel

I want to customize the laravel pagination provided so that it fits the style of my website. The official documentation provides the following command in order to allow for customization.

`php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination`

However, when I use this command, I get the following in my console:-

`Nothing to publish for tag [laravel-pagination].`

The views are not generated in resources/views/vendor folder, as it is supposed to. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just copied a pre-existing pagination file

In `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pagination\resources\views` you can create your own paginator

To call it use

```
{{ $orders->links('pagination::<FileName>') }}
```

Comment: The resources folder does not exist in my particular version.

Answer (score 0):

are you using cached config files ? try using

```
php artisan config:clear
```

and retry

```
php artisan vendor:publish
```